# What is the maximum length of a string?

Tags: string, wix

When I `light` my project, I get the following warning:

```
C:\Users\me\wix\service.wxs(105) : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: 
          String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); 
          Table: ServiceInstall, Column: Description, Key(s): ServiceRegister
```

My `Description` is quite long, but before I set out to trim it down, what is the maximum length permitted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Description` column in `ServiceInstall` table has the `Formatted` type, so technically it doesn't have a limit. You can use any length you want.

The warning is displayed because your current text exceeds 255 characters (standard maximum text length in Windows). It's only a warning, not an error. It doesn't affect your installation.

Still, if you want to avoid the warning, a solution is to use installer properties:

- split your description text into multiple custom properties
- use these properties in your description instead of the actual text

This way the long text will be resolved during install and it's length won't trigger any warnings.

Comment: The ServiceInstall table has size of the Description field set to 255. I can see the same error for table Component column Component, which has size 72 and contains not only the Id from xml but also the GUID of the package, thus id 32 characters long makes this warning, but 31 characters is OK.